# Redirect to protected page after authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, kotlin

By default, spring security after authentication redirects you to protected page you tried to access before.

When I implement my own success handler

```
@Component
class MyS: AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, authentication: Authentication?) {

        response?.sendRedirect(request?.getHeader(HttpHeaders.REFERER))

    }
}
```

---

```
class SecurityConfigTH(@Autowired private val myHandler: MyS) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() { 
...
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/en/login")
        .successHandler(myHandler)
        .permitAll()
 }
```

I cannot achieve the same effect. I tried redirect to referrer, but in this case referrer is /en/login page.

Basically:

1. User try to access protected url `/protected`
2. Redirect user to `/login` page
3. After authentication user should be redirected to `/protected` again

How to do it with custom successHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, i used `DefaultSavedRequest` that completed my requirement. `DefaultSavedRequest` class is used by AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter and SavedRequestAwareWrapper to reproduce the request after successful authentication. An instance of this class is stored at the time of an authentication exception by ExceptionTranslationFilter.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/savedrequest/DefaultSavedRequest.html

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    DefaultSavedRequest defaultSavedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
    if(defaultSavedRequest != null){
       String targetURL = defaultSavedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
       redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetURL);
       return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mhod's answer this did the trick.

```
@Component
class MyS: AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, authentication: Authentication?) {

        val defaultSavedRequest = request?.session?.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST") as DefaultSavedRequest
        response?.sendRedirect(defaultSavedRequest.requestURI)

    }
}
```