# Redirection to originally requested page after successful login is not working in spring boot web mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect, spring-security

I am trying to build web application which uses spring security form login for authentication. Basically, I am trying to build following workflow:

**index.html** is home page of the application, which is accessible to all users and it contains link to a protected page **submitarticle.html**, which is placed inside a folder **author**. When user clicks on the link, it is redirected to loginregister.html page for login process. And, after successful login and the logged in user has role "ROLE_AUTHOR", it redirects to the originally requested page "submitarticle.html". However, it is redirecting to index page.
I have used http header to get the originally requested url as request.getHeader("Referer"). But, when I am on the index page and click on the protected page **submitarticle.html**, "referer" page seems to be index page itself. So, after successful login, it is redirected to index page. Please help me identify what I may be missing here.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        return new CustomSuccessHandler("/");
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/logout", "/register").permitAll();
         
     // submitarticle.html should be accessible to user with role Author only.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/author/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_AUTHOR')");
         // Config for Login Form
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                // Submit URL of login page.
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginregister") // Submit URL                
                .loginPage("/loginregister")//
                .successHandler(successHandler())//
                .failureUrl("/loginregister?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // Config for Logout Page
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/");    
 }
```

CustomSuccessHandler.java

```
public CustomSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {          
            
            setDefaultTargetUrl(defaultTargetUrl);
            setUseReferer(true);
        }
     @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException 
    { 
            Object redirectURLObject = request.getSession().getAttribute("original_url");      
            String url = null;
           if(redirectURLObject != null)
           {
             url = redirectURLObject.toString();          
             getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, url); 
             request.getSession().removeAttribute("original_url");
           }
           // If request url is null then redirect to home page "/"
           else
           {
             getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
           }            
        }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginregister", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginRegisterPage(AuthorRegistrationForm authorRegistrationForm, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
        //save referer URL to session, for later use on CustomAuthenticationSuccesshandler
        request.getSession().setAttribute("original_url", referer);
        
        return "loginregister";
    }
```

loginregister.html

```
<form class="sj-formtheme sj-formlogin" action="/loginregister" method="post">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username*" required="">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password*" required="">
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <div class="sj-btnarea">
                                                        <button name="login-submit" class="sj-btn sj-btnactive">Login</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
```

Comment: well you have a `CustomSuccessHandler` that tells your application to redirect you to `/` which servers your `index.html` after a successful login, try removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem in
[Redirect to protected page after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774497/redirect-to-protected-page-after-authentication)

In CustomSuccessHandler class, I used DefaultSavedRequest object to get the original request object as below:

```
DefaultSavedRequest defaultSavedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");
        if(defaultSavedRequest != null)
           url = defaultSavedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
```

and I used that url for redirection.